# Using JNA/JNI to call C socket functions from Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, java-native-interface, jna

I have to use a third-party library that has some socket functions. I have no access to the source code but it uses some simple functions:

- OpenConn to open a socket connection
- CloseConn to close the connection
- SocketRecv is a blocking function to receive data

These functions use a specific protocol so I can't use Java sockets instead.
Edit: I must use the library since it is a requirement. Discarding the library is not possible.

This is the code I'm using that I will describe below:

```
public class Test {
    private static int descriptor = -1;
    private static int numBytesRecv;
    public static byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
    public static SocketLib lib = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        String server_ip = "0.0.0.0";
        lib = SocketLib.INSTANCE;
        descriptor = lib.OpenConn(server_ip);
        System.out.println("Descriptor: " + Integer.toString(descriptor));

        RecvThread t = new RecvThread();
        t.start();

        int closeResult = lib.CloseConn(descriptor);
        System.out.println("Close result: " + Integer.toString(closeResult));

        t.join();
        System.out.println("Program finish");
    }

    static class RecvThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting RecvThread");
            numBytesRecv = lib.SocketRecv( descriptor, buffer, 255);
            System.out.println("Finishing RecvThread");
        }
    }
```

(JNA definitions code is not included)

I first call to OpenConn to open a connection in the main thread.
Then I start a thread with the SocketRecv function to wait for any data.
Then I close the connection in the main thread.

The expected behaviour would be that, after closing the connection, the socket is closed and the receiving function is released so the program finishes.

If I use a similar C application to test that behaviour, it works OK.

But when using JNA (as in the code above) or JNI to call the C functions, the socket is not closed when I call the CloseConn function and, because of that, the SocketRecv thread never finishes (if no data is received).

Edit: Via debugging, I am sure that the receiving thread is started before the closing function is called. If the close function is called before the SocketRecv, the SocketRecv function does not block and its thread finishes.

What could be causing that the socket is not closed when calling the CloseConn function from Java? I've thought about any issues with the fact that I use a separate Java thread to call the SocketRecv function, but I haven't found any similar case as a reference.

Comment: 'These functions use a specific protocol so I can't use Java sockets instead' is a *non sequitur.* I suggest it would be preferable to reimplement the protocol in Java than to introduce JNI/JNA into your system.

Comment: Of course it would be preferable to use only Java code (or C code since it works as I wrote). I may have not used the right words there. I wanted to point that it's a requirement to use the C library here, their functions can't be reimplemented in Java or another language, only the propietary library can be used (even if I could use reverse engineering to decode the protocol). Edit: and it must be integrated into a Java application.

Comment: There's no guarantee that your receive thread is going to have started running by the time you close the socket.  What code is responsible for setting up the listening socket?  If it's `SocketRecv`, then you should probably start that thread and wait for a signal before attempting the connect.   Depending on the type of socket created, there isn't necessarily _any_ indication of "close" sent to the listener (UDP sockets, for instance, are connectionless).

Comment: @technomage The library uses TCP sockets. I wanted to keep the code example simple but I am sure that the SocketRecv thread is run before the closing part is run. There is an external server socket listening, and the OpenConn connects as a client. SocketRecv waits for a message from the server, and it should end when receiving any message or when the connection is closed with CloseConn.
The problem here is that the library does not work as expected when using Java and JNA/JNI to run it, but if I run it from a C application it works well.

Comment: Enrique, how do you know that receive thread code runs before the connection is closed? You say so, but how do you know? Have tried what happens if the connection is closed before you invoke lib.SocketRecv?

I think technomage maybe on the right track here. The only difference between running the same code in C or Java that comes to mind is threading.

Comment: @nyholku I am debugging the above code so I can track the threads creation. In the full program, the close connection is not called immediately but after a long time. I have added that information to the question.